# simple html dom parser with curl hangs too long on different URL's

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I use simple HTML DOM parser together with curl (I do not have a big experience with curl) and I try to figure out why is hanging on different URL requests long. I have been trying to log with verbose but I did not get back any useful information. It seems like is a Caching problem because after long response all my other requests are acting the same till I clear Browser Cache

str_get_html(get_data($target));

```
function get_data($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 30;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'some useragent');
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` curl option in your request. Are you sure what it does? It sends the `HEAD` request to the target url instead of the `GET`. There are lot of web servers available in the Internet which do accept the `HEAD` request and keep the request in stuck until the timeout occures. And this is what you are experiencing right now.

Comment: Sorry I was giving the wrong snippet even without the problem persist